# How to use @Service annotated class as an @Autowired bean in another class which is outside the component scan package of the Service class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, javabeans, autowired

I have a service interface called ABCService and its implementation called ABCServiceImpl.

ABCService.class

```
package com.abc.service.ABCService;

public interface ABCService{
    //interface methods
}
```

ABCServiceImpl.class

```
package com.abc.service.ABCServiceImpl; 

@Service
public class ABCServiceImpl implements ABCService{
     // implemented methods
}
```

XYZ.class

```
package com.abc.util.XYZ;

public class XYZ{

  @Autowired
  ABCService abcService;

  //methods
}
```

application-context.xml

```
<context: annotation-config>
<context: component-scan base-package="com.abc.service, com.abc.util"/>
```

But when I am trying to use the autowired ABCService in class XYZ to access methods in interface ABCService, I get a null pointer exception.
I then removed the @Service annotation from ABCServiceImpl & added the implentation file in the application-context.xml as a bean & created a bean for class XYZ and gave reference of ABCServiceImpl's bean to bean of class XYZ ; it solved the issue

application-context.xml

```
<bean id="abcService" class="com.abc.service.ABCServiceImpl" />

<bean id="xyz" class="com.abc.util.XYZ" >
    <property name="abcService" ref="abcService"></property>
</bean>
```

but I want to use the @Service annotation itself without explicitly defining a bean in application-context.xml. How do I do it?

Comment: Is it a requirement that class XYZ is outside the package scanned services?

Comment: @Adam : yes XYZ is a utility class and I do not want to put that class in the service package. Hence the XYZ class will be in com.abc.util package

Answer (score 0):

If you want to autowire beans without package scanning, or defining them in XML, then your only option is to do it programmatically using the Spring API...

This is possible using

```
XYZ bean = new XYZ();
context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(bean);
```

Also if you want any @PostConstruct methods to be called, use

```
context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(bean, null);
```